# Problem inserting database using postgres

Tags: postgresql

When i am runing mu insert query too insert into database i am getting an error message like ..
ERROR: permission denied for relation advertiser_regidetdir

How will i resolve this? thanks

Comment: Please always show the actual query in question.

Comment: A permission error means that the user with which you're connecting to the database server does not have "insert" rights to the table you're updating. To solve the problem, you have to either connect as a different user, or change the access control on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permissions to do an INSERT, use GRANT to change this. You must have access to a role that is either superuser or object owner.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html

Comment: can i give permission like mysql  or how will i give Grant permission command?

Comment: Did you check the manual? GRANT INSERT ON TABLE your_table_name TO database_user_name; It's all in the manual, you can find the url above.